# Importing Complex XML into Core Data via NSXMLParser?

Tags: objective-c, xml, core-data

I've been working on importing XML into an iPad Core Data application. I have a working `NSXMLParser` implementation for my files, and have been able to import the simpler (ie attribute-only) elements into Core Data.

Some of the XML dated has nested elements with text, and I'm a bit stumped on how to get Core Data to play nicely in the callback-centric world of NSXML.

If I see a new XML element, I need to insert a new managed object into my context. If I do this in NSXML's `didStartElement:`, I need to preserve a reference to it so that I can store my XML text element when `didEndElement:` is called.

Given that my XML elements are nested, I may have encountered several `didStartElements:` before I encounter a `didEndElement:`, so I need something more than a single object instance to preserve the managed object across callbacks. (Also, I think that `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` is autoreleased, so I need to retain a copy of the managed object.)

I thought I might build an object stack out of `NSMutableArray's` `addObject:` and `removeLastObject:` methods, but I wonder if there's something simpler, or I've missed some piece of the big picture here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run unto a similar problem, and as you mentioned, ended up using stacks with `addObject:`, `lastObject` and `removeLastObject:`. It parses reasonably quickly.

In my specific case, I had a number of Core Data entities, both with instance variables and to-many relationships to their child elements. I used two stacks, one for the objects, and one for the elements. In my case the parent elements did not have data of their own, ex:

```
<Parent>
    <Parent_Data1>Foo</ParentData1>
    <Parent_Data2>Bar</ParentData2>
    <Child>
        <Child_Data1>Baz</Child_Data1>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

So I had one stack of the entities that contained other entities (`Parent` and `Child` in my example), with another containing the keypaths corresponding to the data (`Parent_Data1`, `Parent_Data2` and `Child_Data1`). When I found the data in `parser:foundCharacters` I would set it on the topmost entity using `setValue:forKeyPath:` and pop that when I got to `parser:didEndElement:`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, paxswill- Nice to know I'm not alone in my thinking. Your point about enclosing entities is also well taken. Best wishes, Charles